# AndroidStudio::Flutter:: How to switch between two main files

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I need to switch between two different main files namely `dev.dart` and `prod.dart` the `enntry.dart` contains stateful Material App Widget.

As shown below the image the files:

[image]

I want from android studio to switch between `dev.dart` and `prod.dart`,  as shown below the image:
[image]

I appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Comment: did you try ALT + TAB and ALT + SHIFT + TAB

Comment: @RaviSingh I tried it out. ```It did not work```. Thank you.

Comment: or you can press ALT + arrow keys or if you know the file name simply tap SHIFT 2 times and write the file name, then press ENTER

Comment: @RaviSingh I want switch the runnable file ```dev.dart``` to ```prod.dart``` the circle red marked dorpdown does not show anything it stay stall. thank you

Comment: @RaviSingh I figured it out its ```ctrl``` + ```option``` + ```R```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out; on Mac you go to

- `Run` > `Run`
- Then from the contextual menu you select `Edit Profile` you add both `dev` and `prod` as separate entries.
- after adding both profiles then you can switch between profiles by hitting the short key code `ctrl` + `option` + `r`

Thanks